# How to change jupyter kernel from Python 2 to python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupiter notebook and I only have python 2 as a default kernel. I want to change it from python 2 to python 3. How could I do that?[image: Here is the screenshot.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html
```

Follow the link for managing python. If you use python 2, then install python 3 by using this command.

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

After installing python 3, activate python 3 by using this command

```
activate py36
```

Then open jupyter notebook, you will find python on your kernel.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can activate my environment, then open python and it is 3.8 (as I want it to be), but when I open jupyter notebook, the only option for a new file is in Python 2.

Comment: same here. did you find a way to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the following steps:

1. `conda create -n py36 'python=3.6' ipykernel #Replace 3.6 with desired version.`
2. To activate installed jupyter kernal you need run, `source activate py36`
3. `python -m ipykernel install --user`
4. The interesting part: if you want to switch between kernels (py2-py3) in the same notebook, you need to run, `conda install nb_conda`

However, if at any point you realize that some of the modules are not available, for that you need to check Anaconda Python version.

```
python - version
```

if it is not python 3.x, you need to run

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
source active py36
```

I hope it helps and enjoy switching python versions in the same notebook. You can try to print something in both python2 and python 3.

Comment: step 3 was sufficient for me. This is the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you installed the python/jupyter with anaconda, simply update the python from 2.* to 3.*

Comment: I have tried all. I have downloaded python 3. Could you explain me the process if you don't mind. I had google it as well.

Comment: Please be sure to include more explanation in your answers so that they're useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following steps:

1. Create new env by using python3.

   virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 jupyter_environment
2. Activate env

   source jupyter_environment/bin/activate
3. Start jupyter

   jupyter notebook --allow-root

Then open Jupyter notebook, you will find python3 by default on your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to add Python 3.9 to Jupyter as follows.

```
# cd /usr/share/jupyter/kernels
# ls
python3
# cp python3 python3.9
# cd python3.9
```

and changed `python3` in the `kernel.json` file to `python3.9`:

```
# cat kernel.json 
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3.9",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3.9",
 "language": "python"
```

After this, the kernel may be changed through `Kernel->Change kernel` in Jupyter.

Python 3.9 was installed separately, simply with package manager (zypper in my case).

I think, this should work with Python 2 as well.