# Unexpected broken pipe error in shell pipeline inside Jupyter Notebook terminal

Tags: bash, shell, jupyter-notebook

I encountered `ls: write error: Broken pipe` when I run `ls -l | head` in a directory containing too many files. I did not encounter that problem when running `ls | head`. I just wonder why `-l` option would cause that problem. Also I would like to know how to resolve that problem but still with long information of files printed.

To reproduce my issue, you can first open a within **terminal provided by Jupyter Notebook**,

[image]

and then run the following codes.

```
cd
mkdir test
cd test
for i in {1..200}; do touch $i; done
ls -l | head
```

Output is as follows.

```
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 10
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 100
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 101
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 102
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 103
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 104
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 105
-rw-rw-r-- 1 s1855106 s1855106 0 Apr 14 10:14 106
ls: write error: Broken pipe
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but have a look at [How can I fix a broken pipe error](https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error). Possibly your shell (and hence any command started by it) is ignoring SIGPIPE (as an illustration, `(trap '' PIPE; ls -l | head)` will reliably reproduce your issue). You can see the signal disposition of your `bash` shell  with the  builtin `trap -p`

Comment: I can't reproduce this error - I tried with 20,000 files, but `ls -l | head` works as expected - could be something to do with your shell (bash v5?) or your ls command (gnu ls?) ?

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful comments! I have now found that I will encounter this problem if I use the terminal provided by Jupyter Notebook. All the things are fine if I use other terminal like Git Bash. I have edited my problem accordingly and I appreciate your further help. I am using Jupyter Notebook Terminal mainly because I want to do all the things on web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Python (at least older versions of python2) [doesn't reset SIGPIPE handling for subprocesses](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=859169)

This means that any commands started by it (e.g. commands you start in a Jupyter notebook) will ignore `SIGPIPE`, exactly as if you had issued `trap '' PIPE`. This, in turn, means that commands in a pipeline don't catch the `SIGPIPE` that is sent to them when they try to write to their `stdout` while  the following command (`tail`, in your case) in the pipeline has finished, and thus see a write error instead. See, for example, [this bug report](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/975).

`(trap '' PIPE; ls -l | head)` will reliably reproduce your problem in any (non-Jupyter) shell.

Apparently, [python3 has fixed this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html), so you could try [changing the python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428381/how-to-change-jupyter-kernel-from-python-2-to-python-3)  used by your notebook.  Alternatively, you could try "un-ignoring" `SIGPIPE` by issuing `trap - PIPE`