# How can I change my python version in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python

I have python3 in my jupyter notebook but I want to make it for python2 as well. How can I install for both versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492623/using-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: Why? Python 2 is obsolete for years already.

Answer (score 0):

First click to kernel tab, then a dropdown menu will show up. Click change kernel and select python 2. If python 2 didn't show up check out this:

[How to change jupyter kernel from Python 2 to python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428381/how-to-change-jupyter-kernel-from-python-2-to-python-3)

You can make it reverse.

Comment: I don't see any kernel option in my jupyter.

Comment: Sorry It's there but no python2 option.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter will launch with the python version that is installed on the environment you're working in.

If you want to use multiple versions of python, you can use an environment management system like [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/) to create different environments with different versions of python.

[Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) is a light version of conda that you could use to get what you want.