# Getting this numpy- module not found error in Jupyter Notebook. Unable to proceed

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Please help in resolving this error.

[image]

Numpy is already installed. [image]

Comment: What Python environment is your Jupyter Notebook running?

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40694528/17769815

Comment: yes it is working with 3.10.2. I even had uninstalled the 3.10 version still it is working with that.

Comment: how do I change the environment to 3.9?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363836/17769815

Comment: i have tried all that doesnt seem to work plus I do not have anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip to install the numpy first.
Copy and run this code in your first cell.

```
!pip install numpy
```

If you need to upgrade pip then copy and run the below command in your first cell followed by the above command.

```
!python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

You may have to restart your kernal after updating pip. Use restart option from Jupyter Notebook `kernal` option. see screenshot for reference.
[image: Kernal Restart]

**Another Option**

If you want to downgrade your python from 3.10 to 3.9, as numpy is yet not supported by python 3.10. Then you can downgrade your python version from 3.10 to 3.9 via conda.

```
!conda install python=3.9
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue agin I need to first change the python version from 3.10 to 3.9 somehow please help in doing that. ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: Have you installed Anaconda?

Comment: no sorry, i do not have anaconda I am a beginner i started this today and had 2 versions of python installed which lead to all the trouble and then realized NumPy works only with 3.9.

Comment: when i do pip install it leads to the error that I pasted above

Comment: Install Anaconda. Then you can use whatever version of python for your project.