# How to use a specific version (something lower than 3.4) of python in jupyter notebook or google colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, version, google-colaboratory

I have to do data-analysis on brain data and there are some requirements that need to be met before I can load the data. One of the requirements is that my python version should be lower than 3.4.
My group and I want to work on the code together in google colab but doing it in jupyter notebook initially is fine as well. I just can't find a way to run code with a lower python version. Without a lower version it just won't work. I know I can do `!apt-get install python3.3` and that appears to work. When I call `!python --version` however, it still gives 3.7.12 as an output. How do I make sure I can run my code in an older version?

Comment: Your _default_ Python is still the 3.7 one. You want to use a virtual environment manager - I recommend `pipenv`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428381/how-to-change-jupyter-kernel-from-python-2-to-python-3)

I'm not sure if you can achieve this in google colab. You can try to uninstall a version and then install the one you want.